# don't want to add column name in datatable

Tags: asp.net, datatable

I am doing something like this 
dt.Columns.Add("SomeCoumnName");
But I don't want to display this column name after binding it to the gridview.
Just want to show a blank header for particular column.

Answer (score 2):

Set AutoGenerateColumns="false" in Gridview and create custom header like in given sample. If you don't want to show header for a particular column then set HeaderText="" in <asp:BoundField ...>

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdSearch" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">            
            <Columns>                
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="County" 
                  DataField="Prop_County" SortExpression="Prop_County" ItemStyle-Width="70px" HeaderStyle-Height="25px">                    
                </asp:BoundField>                
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Sale Date" 
                  DataField="Prop_Sale_Date" ItemStyle-Width="55px"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Sale Time" 
                  DataField="Prop_Sale_Time" ItemStyle-Width="55px"></asp:BoundField>                
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Bid Amount" 
                  DataField="Prop_Bid_Amnt" ItemStyle-Width="100px"></asp:BoundField>                
            </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply. Actually I cannot use your solution as I am dynamically creating DataTable to bind it to Gridview.
So the column may vary according to the datatable. I got the solution for my problem, after binding Gridview we can loop through like this 
foreach (TableCell tc in GridView.HeaderRow.Cells)
                { tc.Text = " ";}